# Custom DataGenerator tensorflow error 'ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have a 2-channeled imagelike file from which I am cutting patches as training/validation datasets for a convolutional autoencoder. I am using a custom data generator from TensorFlow to use different data for each batch and epoch.

Here is my `CustomDataGenerator` class:

```
class CustomDataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, file, sample_size, batch_size=32, width=28, height=28, resolution=(28, 28)):
        'Initialization'
        self.sample_size = sample_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(self.sample_size / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'

        batch = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
           ....

        x = np.asarray(batch)
        x = tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 3, 1])
        return x, x
```

and training code:

```
...
    train_gen = data_generator.CustomDataGenerator(file=file, sample_size=10000)
    val_gen = data_generator.CustomDataGenerator(file=file, sample_size=2000)
    history = autoencoder.fit(train_gen, epochs=100, validation_data=val_gen)
...
```

when I run the code it throws:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'data_generator.CustomDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

in `model.fit` line during training.

tensorflow ==2.5.0, keras ==2.4.3

Comment: Where did you define `data_generator`?

Comment: in the same folder as training file

Comment: Have you imported all layers and functions from `tensorflow.keras.*` and not from `keras.*`? Sometimes mixing these libraries leads to issues.

Comment: Here is my import part for data_generator.py:

import numpy as np
import keras
import utils
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py
from numpy import random

Comment: change `import keras` to `from tensorflow import keras` and check it again.

Comment: it did not help, I had explicitly inherited `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`

Answer (score 1):

Your `__getitem__` method must return X, Y pairs. Why you are returning X, X instead?

The train_gen then is passed to model.fit() to train. The error is due to that you are sending X as Y parameter to your model.fit()

PS: you can use `on_epoch_end`. This function will be called at the end of every epoch by the fit method.

Comment: I am using data generator for autoencoder where inputs X and labels y are the same

Comment: btw, what are you getting when run `next(train_gen)` without executing autoencoder.fit()?

Comment: TypeError: 'CustomDataGenerator' object is not an iterator